Orthogonality of solutions to an eigenproblem
Let $\Omega$ be a connected, closed region in $R^2$, with $\Gamma$ being its boundary. ($\Gamma$ is piecewise smooth and non-self-intersecting but may not be necessarily connected - there may be one or more "holes" in $\Omega$ with internal boundaries accordingly.)
Let $\Gamma$ be divided into two mutually exclusive regions $\Gamma_D,\Gamma_N$ where the boundary between the two is some finite set of points and all such boundary points are in $\Gamma_D$.
Let $\mu: \Omega \rightarrow R^+$ be a positive-valued function, finite and bounded away from zero, and continuous almost everywhere.
Consider the eigenvalue/eigenfunctionpairs ${\lambda}_i, f_i:\Omega \rightarrow R$ satisfying a Laplacian differential equation with Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions:
$${-\Delta}f_i(\vec{x}) = {\lambda}_i{\mu}(\vec{x})f_i(\vec{x}) \forall \vec{x}\in \Omega$$
$$f_i(\vec{x}) = 0 \forall \vec{x}\in{\Gamma}_D$$
$${\nabla}f_i(\vec{x}) \bullet \vec{n}(\vec{x}) = 0 \forall \vec{x} \in {\Gamma}_N$$
where $\vec{n}(\vec{x})$ is a unit normal vector to ${\Gamma}_N$ at $\vec{x}$.
For functions $f,g,h$ defined on $\Omega$, define the inner product of $f$ and $g$ weighted by $h$ as:
$$\langle f,g,h \rangle = \int_\Omega f(\vec{x})g(\vec{x})h(\vec{x}) dA$$
In the well-known case where $\Omega = [0,1]^2$, $\Gamma_N = \Gamma$ and $\mu(\vec{x})=1\forall\vec{x}$, the solutions are a 2-dimensional Fourier basis set of the form:
$$f_{m,n}(\vec{x}) = \cos{(m\pi{x})}\cos{(n\pi{y})}, \lambda_{m,n} = \pi^2(m^2+n^2)$$
If instead $\Gamma_D = \Gamma$, we get a similar solution based on sine functions instead of cosine.
For those two cases, it's well known that these solutions are orthogonal: $\forall (m_1,n_1)\ne(m_2,n_2),\langle f_{m_1,n_1},f_{m_2,n_2},1\rangle = 0 $
Having coded up a method to find approximate solutions for other choices of $\Omega$ and $\mu$, it looks to me that the orthogonality property generalises when weighting by $\mu$:
$$\forall m,n:\lambda_m\ne\lambda_n,\langle f_m,f_n,\mu\rangle = 0 $$
Is this correct, either for the problem as stated above or for some appropriate restriction of it? (I've been focussing more on Neumann conditions, which are more relevant to my application, so I haven't tested Dirichlet or mixed boundary conditions as much. Feel free to insert any well-behavedness assumptions as needed, I'm not expecting to be dealing with pathological functions.)

Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be solutions of the $\mu$-weighted eigenproblem corresponding to distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. For the following computation, I will assume they are real and nonzero. Now define $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mu$ to be the $1$ and $\mu$-weighted $L^2$ inner products on $\Omega$, respectively. We then have
$$
\lambda_1\langle u_1, u_2\rangle_\mu = \langle \lambda_1 u_1, u_2\rangle_\mu = \langle \lambda_1\mu u_1, u_2 \rangle = \langle -\Delta u_1, u_2 \rangle = \langle u_1, -\Delta u_2 \rangle = \langle u_1, \lambda_2\mu u_2 \rangle = \langle u_1, \lambda_2 u_2 \rangle_\mu = \overline{\lambda_2}\langle u_1, u_2\rangle_\mu.
$$
Our equation reads $\lambda_1\langle u_1, u_2\rangle_\mu = \overline{\lambda_2}\langle u_1, u_2\rangle_\mu$. However, since $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are nonzero, real, and distinct, we must have $\langle u_1,u_2 \rangle_\mu = 0$. The eigenvalues we selected were arbitrary, so this property is true for eigenfunctions corresponding to any distinct real eigenvalues.
We now discuss whether the eigenvalues are real and nonzero. If we have Dirichlet conditions anywhere on the boundary, then it is well-known that the Laplacian has all positive eigenvalues. This combined with $\mu$ being bounded away from zero gives unifrom ellipticity and we are done. In the Neumann case, the constant function is the only null eigenfunction and the preceding argument can prove orthogonality.
As for whether the eigenvalues are real, notice that the operator $L = -\mu^{-1}\Delta$ with appropriate boundary conditions satisfies
$$
\langle v, Lu \rangle_\mu = \langle v, -\Delta u \rangle = \langle -\Delta v, u \rangle = \langle Lv, u \rangle,
$$
so it is self-adjoint w.r.t. the $L^2(\Omega;\mu)$ inner product and hence has real eigenvalues. Also note that if you started from this, this immediately implies $\mu$-orthogonality of the eigenfunctions, but the direct proof is easy enough.

Thanks! I didn't follow the step $\langle -\Delta u_1, u_2 \rangle = \langle u_1, -\Delta u_2 \rangle$ - are you able to clarify this? I'm also missing where the conjugate comes from in $\langle u_1, \lambda_2 u_2 \rangle_\mu = \overline{\lambda_2}\langle u_1, u_2\rangle_\mu$ but that's less of an issue, given that the eigenvalues are real.


Write as an integral and use Green’s identities and the homogeneous BC’s. 2. That’s just how complex inner products work.


Ah right - I didn't have complex values in mind when I wrote up the question, so the definition I used for inner product is missing the conjugate. That makes sense now. I will accept this answer once I've worked through that last step with Green's identities.

(Edited my question to change an erroneous cross product in the Neumann condition to a dot product, but I think you had already answered the question as intended rather than as I'd written it.)
